# Is there a difference between pop() and pop(-1)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know they virtually do the same thing, but is their time complexity the same, too? Or does the version with -1 go through the entire list first?

I couldn't find a conclusive answer anywhere.

Comment: "Or does the version with -1 go through the entire list first" why would it? I don't really understand your concern. But no, there shouldn't be any difference. If there were, that would be a pretty serious implementation flaw (since you can analytically convert `-1` to `len(mylist) - 1`). You could always try creating lists of increasing size and seeing how both `pop()` and `pop(-1)` scale. But again, there is no good reason to believe they should behave any differently and a good reason to believe they should behave exactly the same.

Comment: Why would it go through the entire list?  Any negative index just gets subtracted from the length of the list, which is something that the list keeps track of (it doesn't require any sort of loop to calculate).

Comment: Thank you! In that case, lst.extend(x) where x is a list of length 1 is constant too, right? It would be like appending one value?

Comment: @pmadik yes. yes it would.

Comment: @pmadik yes, it is; but you could just use `append`. Also, you should probably read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), where it's all written...

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference; [the code the implements `list.pop`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/14b7f00fdf9890739b43a3e198e4ce93f54c0552/Objects/listobject.c#L996) actually treats a failure to provide an argument as if you passed `-1`, so the code paths (aside from parsing the argument in the first place, which isn't needed when no argument is given) are identical.

You don't even need to rely on the source code to prove this; [the mutable sequence documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) explicitly says in a note for `pop`:

> The optional argument `i` defaults to `-1`, so that by default the last item is removed and returned.

It's not an implementation detail that `-1` is used, it's actually defined that way in the spec, rather than having a special case for no argument (which makes sense; who wants to write a special case code path when you could just reuse the same code path for all calls?).

Comment: For anyone looking for where the logic for using `-1` as a default is, it's in [`list_pop`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a87c46eab3c306b1c5b8a072b7b30ac2c50651c0/Objects/clinic/listobject.c.h#L124), which is called just before the `list_pop_impl` function linked in the answer.

Comment: @Brian: Though to be clear, the `listobject.c.h` you link is a generated file, no human touches it (the actual maintained "code" that generates it is the Argument Clinic header I direct linked; the code is generated from the `index: Py_ssize_t = -1` line; looks like a comment, effectively code).